# How to convert a bytes32 to string

Tags: solidity, string, bytes32

How can I convert a `bytes32` to a `string`? Does anyone has a magic function or library which does it?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/how-to-concatenate-a-bytes32-array-to-a-string

Comment: This about concatenating, isn't it?

Comment: is this a question for solidity or for outside the blockchain e.g. in javascript?

Comment: No, just in the blockchain. I made another question with the js part

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on the latest compiler version 0.4.24, I use the following.

```
function convertingToString()public returns(string){
bytes32 memory hw = "Hello World";
string memory converted = string(hw);
return converted;
}
```

Using explicit conversion to carry it out. The reverse is also possible.

For versions 0.5.0+ please use (tested from 0.5 to 0.7.2 - it is likely that it will continue to work past 0.7.2):

```js
function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string memory) {
        uint8 i = 0;
        while(i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(i);
        for (i = 0; i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0; i++) {
            bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
        }
        return string(bytesArray);
    }
```

Comment: This does not work in solidity version 0.5.0+

Comment: and what does??

Comment: updated for solidity version past 0.5.0

Comment: does not work getting this error `
Failed to decode output: null: invalid codepoint at offset 2; missing continuation byte (argument="bytes", value={"0":91,"1":218,"2":113,"3":98,"4":184,"5":77,"6":255,"7":114,"8":27,"9":203,"10":143,"11":119,"12":114,"13":120,"14":180,"15":136,"16":222,"17":216,"18":209,"19":71,"20":82,"21":100,"22":212,"23":54,"24":28,"25":107,"26":10,"27":191,"28":204,"29":42,"30":153,"31":168}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=strings/5.1.0)
`  was trying to convert this string `0x5bda7162b84dff721bcb8f777278b488ded8d1475264d4361c6b0abfcc2a99a8`

Answer (score 41):

As of feb 2021 you can do

```
bytes32 foo = "hello";
string memory bar = string(abi.encodePacked(foo));
```

Comment: As soon as StackOverfloor gets the system vote from Medium, I'll give other 10 upvotes.

Comment: Failed to decode output: null: invalid codepoint at offset 2; missing continuation byte (argument="bytes"....

Comment: unfortunately it keeps zero padding which might be a problem in some cases..

Comment: How would you remove the zero padding?

Answer (score 31):

Here's one:

```
function bytes32ToString(bytes32 x) constant returns (string) {
    bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
    uint charCount = 0;
    for (uint j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(x) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
        if (char != 0) {
            bytesString[charCount] = char;
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    bytes memory bytesStringTrimmed = new bytes(charCount);
    for (j = 0; j < charCount; j++) {
        bytesStringTrimmed[j] = bytesString[j];
    }
    return string(bytesStringTrimmed);
}
```

To test, here it is combined with how to [concatenate an array of `bytes32`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1081/42).  Paste the following in [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org).

```
contract C {
    function bytes32ToString(bytes32 x) constant returns (string) {
        bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
        uint charCount = 0;
        for (uint j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(x) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
            if (char != 0) {
                bytesString[charCount] = char;
                charCount++;
            }
        }
        bytes memory bytesStringTrimmed = new bytes(charCount);
        for (j = 0; j < charCount; j++) {
            bytesStringTrimmed[j] = bytesString[j];
        }
        return string(bytesStringTrimmed);
    }

    function bytes32ArrayToString(bytes32[] data) returns (string) {
        bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(data.length * 32);
        uint urlLength;
        for (uint i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            for (uint j=0; j<32; j++) {
                byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(data[i]) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
                if (char != 0) {
                    bytesString[urlLength] = char;
                    urlLength += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        bytes memory bytesStringTrimmed = new bytes(urlLength);
        for (i=0; i<urlLength; i++) {
            bytesStringTrimmed[i] = bytesString[i];
        }
        return string(bytesStringTrimmed);
    }    
}
```

Click "Create".  Then in `bytes32ToString` field enter
`"0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"` and click `bytes32ToString`.

In `bytes32ArrayToString` field enter
`["0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"]` and click `bytes32ArrayToString`.

Both will show same result (ABI encoding):
Result: `"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"`

---

Here's another example.  In `bytes32ToString` field enter
`"0xc3b6"` and click `bytes32ToString`.  You will get `ö`.

[image]

Comment: I used the bytes32ToString function from above, but I obviously doesn't work with special characters such as ö ä ü etc. Is there a way to use this function with special characters?

Comment: @Bumblebee I added an example for ö and it works.  If still needed, probably ask a separate question.  (The input or decoding the output might be your problem.)

Comment: I am trying your `bytes32ArrayToString` with a fixed `bytes32[10]`, but it seems I throw an `invalid opcode` if I use 8-10 full slots of the array. Meaning I have a test for `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef` (32 characters) 10 times in an array and pass that in, but it throws. If I have 7 or less it works. Any idea why?

Comment: @TheNomad Not sure. Suggestions, try once instead of 10 times, and post a new question (a Remix or ethfiddle link might help).

Comment: @Russo It's not clear what you're trying to do in Python; Stackoverflow is a better fit for questions about converting from different Python types.

Comment: Had no idea a string was an array of bytes.. Learned something new today! thanks!

Answer (score 12):

How to convert a bytes32 to string:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Bytes32ToString {

function bytes32ToStr(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string) {

    // string memory str = string(_bytes32);
    // TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "string storage pointer"
    // thus we should fist convert bytes32 to bytes (to dynamically-sized byte array)

    bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(32);
    for (uint256 i; i < 32; i++) {
        bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
        }
    return string(bytesArray);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended you convert a `bytes32` to a `string` using Web3.js to avoid gas costs. To do this, you would get the value of the `bytes32` from Solidity to the front end then do:

`web3.utils.hexToString(bytes32);`

This will convert the `bytes32` to a `string` that you can then see and use in your frontend dApp.

Answer (score 2):

In version 0.5.0 and above i ended up with using Viktor answer [How to convert a bytes32 to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string#answer-31292)  **but removing the zeros** otherwise you will end up with

`'ERC20\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000'`

instead of

`'ERC20'`

This is the code:

```
/* bytes32 (fixed-size array) to string (dynamically-sized array) */
function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string memory) {
        uint8 i = 0;
        while(i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(i);
        for (i = 0; i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0; i++) {
            bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
        }
        return string(bytesArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @e18r already mentioned, the simplest way to do it without having to write all these crazy functions like everyone else is answering with (and would cost more gas), just do:

`string(abi.encodePacked(bytes32));`

Comment: unfortunately it seems to keep zero padding which might be a problem in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, if you want to convert bytes32 to ASCII string, you can use the OpenZeppelin Strings library.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/2504

```
Strings.toHexString(uint256(tokenIdSeed), 32),
```

The output should be like

```
0xd8df8ecd5432b247d2fc2beb0619d637e9de0df7512bd36220582deda9a1df6e
```

(this is just covert hexadecimal value of the bytes32 to string)

Comment: This is the simplest and most elegant solution among all the answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A more gas-efficient method based on [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/59335/96505) (For versions 0.5.0+):

```
function toString(bytes32 source)
    internal
    pure
    returns (string memory result)
{
    uint8 length = 0;
    while (source[length] != 0 && length < 32) {
        length++;
    }
    assembly {
        result := mload(0x40)
        // new "memory end" including padding (the string isn't larger than 32 bytes)
        mstore(0x40, add(result, 0x40))
        // store length in memory
        mstore(result, length)
        // write actual data
        mstore(add(result, 0x20), source)
    }
}
```

This solution is using assembly to copy data to memory instead of `for` looping.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
function char(byte b) returns (byte c) {
    if (b < 10) return byte(uint8(b) + 0x30);
    else return byte(uint8(b) + 0x57);
}


function bytes32string(bytes32 b32) returns (string out) {
    bytes memory s = new bytes(64);

    for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        byte b = byte(b32[i]);
        byte hi = byte(uint8(b) / 16);
        byte lo = byte(uint8(b) - 16 * uint8(hi));
        s[i*2] = char(hi);
        s[i*2+1] = char(lo);            
    }

    out = string(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
    contract stringtobytes{
        function set(string memory  _a)public pure returns(bytes memory){
            return bytes(_a);
        } 
         function set1(bytes memory  _a)public pure returns(string  memory){
            return string(_a);
        } 

}
```

// you  can  convert strings to bytes(in decimal format) and vice versa with below code

//1- bytes1=8bit=2decimal

//2  bytes2=16bit=4decimal

//3  bytes3=24bit=6decimal

//4  bytes=dynamic array and reference value

Comment: The question is about conversion from bytes32 to string, and your example doesn't work for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way i tried

```
contract ModifyString{
    
    bytes32 public VoterName;

    mapping (address => VoterStruct) public voterCalls;

    struct VoterStruct{
       address VoterAddress;
       string VoterID;
       bytes32 VoterName2;
    }
    
    function addVoter(string memory _VoterID, string memory _VoterName)public {
       // Load Voter struct trough mapping
       VoterStruct storage newVoter = voterCalls[msg.sender];
            
       // If want to write to global variable
       VoterName = bytes32(abi.encodePacked( _VoterName));

       // If want to write to struct
       newVoter.VoterAddress = msg.sender;
       newVoter.VoterID = _VoterID;
       newVoter.VoterName2 = bytes32(abi.encodePacked(_VoterName));
    }

    function getVoterName() public view returns (string memory) {

       // To load from Global Variables
       bytes memory bytesData = abi.encodePacked(VoterName);

       return string(abi.encodePacked(VoterName));
    }
    
    function getVoterName2() public view returns (string memory) {

       // To look Voter name in global variable
       bytes memory bytesData = abi.encodePacked(VoterName);

       return string(abi.encodePacked(bytesData));
    }
    
    function getVoterName3() public view returns (string memory) {

       // To look Voter name in struct
       VoterStruct storage voterCall = voterCalls[msg.sender];

       return string(abi.encodePacked(voterCall.VoterName2));
    }
}
```

so to load the string, it need to be loaded in memory,
as far as i know, string = bytes  (without specific bytes number)

then return the output value using

```
string(abi.encodePacked(bytesData))

 
 ^^^^                      ^^^^^
//The converted type to   //Loaded Variable into memory or storage
```

ahh so there is to:
1.1 Write String to bytes32 to Global Variable,
1.2 Load string from bytes32 from Gobal Variable,
2.1  Write String to bytes32 to Struct,
2.2 Load String to bytes32 to struct.