# How to join strings with numbers in Solidity

Tags: solidity, string

I'd like to format url with number parameters as following:

`http://someurl.com/?param1=100&param2=200`

The problem is, it's always truncated after first number parameter e.g:

`http://someurl.com/?param1=100`. Not sure why.

In my contract I'm using strings library https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils

contract code:

```
import "strings.sol";

contract MyContract {
    using strings for *;

    function bytes32ToString (bytes32 data) constant returns (string) {
        bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
        for (uint j=0; j<32; j++) {
            byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(data) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
            if (char != 0) {
                bytesString[j] = char;
            }
        }
        return string(bytesString);
    }

    function uintToBytes(uint v) constant private returns (bytes32 ret) {
        if (v == 0) {
            ret = '0';
        }
        else {
            while (v > 0) {
                ret = bytes32(uint(ret) / (2 ** 8));
                ret |= bytes32(((v % 10) + 48) * 2 ** (8 * 31));
                v /= 10;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    function uintToString(uint v) constant private returns (string ret) {
        return bytes32ToString(uintToBytes(v));
    }

    function formatUrl(uint param1, uint param2) constant returns(string) {
        var parts = new strings.slice[](4);
        parts[0] = "http://someurl.com/?param1=".toSlice();
        parts[1] = uintToString(param1).toSlice();
        parts[2] = "&?param2=".toSlice();
        parts[3] = uintToString(param2).toSlice();

        return "".toSlice().join(parts);
    }
}
```

So calling `formatUrl(100, 200)` returns `"http://someurl.com/?param1=100"`

If I changed function like this:

```
function formatUrl(uint param1, uint param2) constant returns(string) {
        var parts = new strings.slice[](4);
        parts[0] = "http://someurl.com/?param1=".toSlice();
        parts[3] = uintToString(param1).toSlice();
        parts[1] = "&?param2=".toSlice();
        parts[2] = uintToString(param2).toSlice();

        return "".toSlice().join(parts);
    }
```

I get output: `"http://someurl.com/?param1=&?param2=200"`

It always ends after inserting first number converted to string.

Comment: After pasting your base code into browser-solidity, I get ` http://someurl.com/?param1=100&?param2=200`, which as far as I understand is the desired output. How do you test this?

Comment: I'm compiling locally using solc `Version: 0.3.5-48238c9f/Release-Darwin/appleclang/JIT`. Browser solidity is using now `0.3.6-3fc68da5/Release-Emscripten/clang`. I don't know maybe it's that. Anyways 0.3.5 is latest version on npm

Comment: are you sure you have the most recent `strings.sol` code? Can you maybe try pasting the `strings.sol` code from github directly into your file to make sure that the correct file gets imported?

Comment: I re-pasted now, same result :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I eventually figured out. The problem was in `bytes32ToString` function. It always returns 32 character long string, where rest of unused chars are simply zero bytes and zero byte means end of a string. So that's why I couldn't join anything after such string, because it had zero bytes in it.

So this is edited `bytes32ToString` function. It doesn't return any zero bytes. There might exist more effective way tho. Improvements appreciated.

```
function bytes32ToString (bytes32 x) constant returns (string) {
    bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
    uint charCount = 0;
    for (uint j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        byte char = byte(bytes32(uint(x) * 2 ** (8 * j)));
        if (char != 0) {
            bytesString[charCount] = char;
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    bytes memory resultBytes = new bytes(charCount);
    for (j = 0; j < charCount; j++) {
        resultBytes[j] = bytesString[j];
    }

    return string(resultBytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed (and re-tested) http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string