# Solidity return string not hex?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, javascript, string

Currently I'm using ether.camp to create a contract. At this stage it simply gets and stores some values. However when I try and get the values they are in bytes/hex even though the return type is string?

How do I convert this back to string in the solidity contract? I've tried [How to convert a bytes32 to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string) but no luck

E.g storing "Hello World!" returns  `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c48656c6c6f20576f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

```
   contract HelloWorld {
    struct Items {
       address id;
       string data;
    }

    mapping(address => Items) items;

    function getItem(address key) returns (string) {
      return items[key].data;
    }

    function addItem (address key, string data) returns (bool) {
        Items item = items[key];
        item.data = data;
    }

   }

 }
```

I can see in the ethercamp transactions side bar of the IDE the "Hello World!" is saved as a string but my `getItem()` just can't retrieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) like `contractInstance.getItem.call(key)`.

Or mark getItem as constant: `function getItem(address key) constant returns (string)` and then [you can use:](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)

`contractInstance.getItem(key)`

web3.js will automatically decode the bytes for you.  Contracts only have binary data, hex is a more compact way of viewing that data, and that's why you see hex. The binary data is also encoded according to an [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts), so that values can be distinguished, for example between what's just a number and a string.

Comment: Great thanks! adding `constant` solves it but I know understand webjs will auto decode it for me

Comment: No problem. (I was going to add more clarification about not needing to "convert this back to string in the solidity contract", and good the answer works for you.)

Comment: Perhaps this merits a new question, but is there an easy one-liner to get the count of Items in the above code? Coming from a .net background I had `items.count` or `items.length` in mind.

Comment: Not the way your code is set up. You can't iterate through a mapping, but if you include an array of addresses, you can get the length of that easily.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can also use:

```
> web3.toUtf8("0x48656c6c6f20576f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
Hello World!
```