# Convertion from bytes 8,16,32 to String

Tags: solidity, string, bytes32

I know it has been asked a lot of times but the newest post about this I could find was about 1 year old. To me it seems quite possible that things have changed since then. So my question: Is there an easy way to convert **bytes8/16/32 to a String** value?

Here is the problem I face right now. Contract A takes one user-input per transaction as a bytes8/16/32 variable. The contract passes it to Contract B and stores it there. My getter function in Contract B returns this Bytes8/16/32 variable. So Contract A calls the getter-function of B if needed and successfully gets the bytes variable back. Now I simply want to turn it back to a readable string and put it on screen in a decoded way :)
Somebody has an idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're invoking your Ethereum contract from JavaScript.  If that's the case, you probably need [`web3.toAscii()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii)

```
var str = web3.toAscii("0x657468657265756d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
console.log(str); // "ethereum"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your need for a readable string is just for the Web interface and you are using web3.js you can use :

```
var str = web3.toUtf8("0x657468657265756d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
console.log(str); // "ethereum"
```

`web3.toAscii` can still return some not desirable characters, and since UTF-8 is most used, i suggest the `web3.toUtf8`

An other way is to try and parse the bytes32 to a readable string inside your contract. to do so please refer to this question it has the best answer.

[How to convert a bytes32 to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string)