# Getting infinite gas estimates for simple functions

Tags: solidity, gas, remix, gas-estimate

I am testing out solidity in remix ide using simple contracts. This is the contract that I wrote:

```
 contract mortal {

address owner;

function mortal() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function kill(){
    if(msg.sender == owner){
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
   }
}

contract Hello is mortal
{

string public message;

function Hello(){
    message = 'This is the initial Message';
    }

function getMessage() public constant returns(string){
    return message;
    }

function setNewMessage(string newMessage) public payable {
    message = newMessage;   
    }
}
```

On looking at details I am getting infinite gas estimates for each of these functions.

```
{
"Creation": {
    "codeDepositCost": "243200",
    "executionCost": "infinite",
    "totalCost": "infinite"
},
"External": {
    "getMessage()": "infinite",
    "kill()": "30636",
    "message()": "infinite",
    "setNewMessage(string)": "infinite"
}
}
```

Please elaborate why am I getting infinite gasEstimates for these functions and how can I avoid this mistake ?

Comment: where is contract `mortal`?

Comment: I updated by question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The contract compiles just fine:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract mortal {
    address owner;

    function mortal() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function kill() public {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }
}

contract Hello is mortal {
    string public message;

    function Hello() public {
        message = 'This is the initial Message';
    }

    function getMessage() public constant returns(string) {
        return message;
    }

    function setNewMessage(string newMessage) public payable {
        message = newMessage;   
    }
}
```

> but then the warnings appear...

[image]

> but it submits/confirms on Ropsten just fine..

[image]

> and the method calls work fine too..

[image]

This may just be a bug in the compiler's static analysis.

Comment: I see it is executing, it maybe a bug in remix as you pointed out. Thankyou :)

Comment: The warning is just that. It doesn't mean that the contract won't work; it just means that the gas usage is potentially unbounded. I think that the warning is correct.

Comment: @smarx, yes I see your point, as the string type appears to be unbound

Comment: @smarx  So if string is unbounded, what is the best alternative for storing string data ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's wrong with just using string? If you want to limit the length of the string users can supply, you could check the length. (E.g. require(newMessage.length <= 20);)

Comment: @AhsanJamal You can use `bytes32` or any number of bytes in place of `string`. Just make sure that the bytes can support necessary information.
You can then easily convert the bytes to string easily.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string

Answer (score 8):

I suspect this is because the cost of those functions is indeed unbounded. Strings can be of any length, so `setNewMessage()` needs to store an unbounded amount of data, and `getMessage()` needs to read an unbounded amount of data.

If you want to avoid that warning, you'd have to use a data type with a fixed upper bound on its size.

Comment: I don't know what an "out of gas limit" is (maybe the infinite gas warning being discussed?) but please do add an answer if you believe you have a solution.

Comment: Just to confirm, I see the same infinite gas warnings as OP when using Solidity 0.4.19 on Remix.

Comment: Even if I change the type from string to Bytes32, I am still getting infinite gas for these functions.

Comment: Switching to `bytes32` gets rid of the warning for me.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Seems reasonable enough

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the right answer. I assume it was downvoted by @Victory or by someone else who saw their comment (which made it seem like this answer was incorrect).

Comment: I deleted my old comment, this A was correct. I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using string which does not has a particular size i.e., it is unbound data type. You can use bytes32 in place of string to limit the cost of gas on execution code because solidity considers it a 32 bit literal.

Comment: That said, is it true people should avoid using string at any cost, since it will always return infinite gas usage.