# Remix gas estimate to be infinite for a super simple contract

Tags: remix, gas-estimate

I have an extremely basic contract, but saw infinite execution cost on Remix. Any insights will be appreciated.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Config {

    address public a;

    constructor (address _a) {
        a = _a;
    }
}
```

Remix gas estimate:

```
{
    "Creation": {
        "codeDepositCost": "49400",
        "executionCost": "infinite",
        "totalCost": "infinite"
    },
    "External": {
        "personalAddress()": "2489"
    }
}
```

Comment: where can you see the estimated gas? have you added an extra plugin to remix?

Comment: After you compile a contract, click "Compilation Details" =, then click "Gasestimates".

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug. Sometimes Remix behave weird.

Check this post, This guy tested it on a testnet and proved that its just a bug
[Getting infinite gas estimates for simple functions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34563/getting-infinite-gas-estimates-for-simple-functions)

Comment: Thanks. I saw the other post. The other contract uses string. The gas usage ineed can be unbounded. Seems reasonable to think it is a remix bug.