# Recovering data from Bytes using Assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly

I have im my js file 3 variables:

```
var stringData = "stingData";
var intNonce = 1234;
var hexData = "0x65225648";
```

I want to concatenate then and send to my contract:

```
var data = stringData+intNonce+hexData;
myContract.contractFunction(data);
```

And im my contract i want to recover the 3 variables;

```
contract MyContract {
   contractFunction(bytes memory _data){
      //recover 3 variables
}
}
```

I read that the best way to do this is through Assembly but I have no idea how to implement this

Comment: May be a dupe of this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameters) to encode parameters from the js side.

```
const result = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
    ['string','uint256','bytes32'],
    ["stingData", 1234, "0x65225648"],
)
console.log(result)
```

Which returns

> 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d2652256480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000097374696e67446174610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Then you can decode from the solidity side using [`abi.decode`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions). In the example it will look like this

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

contract A {
    function foo(bytes memory data) public pure returns (string memory, uint256, bytes32) {
        (string memory aString, uint256 aUint, bytes32 aBytes32) = abi.decode(
            data,
            (string, uint256, bytes32)
        );
        return (aString, aUint, aBytes32);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot! That was exactly that I needed