# Can arguments be bytes32[] type?

Tags: contract-development, mist

I read from this question [How to concatenate a bytes32[] array to a string?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/how-to-concatenate-a-bytes32-array-to-a-string)(the first answer) that the agrument can be bytes32[] type, but when I try myself sending transactions using mist setting the argument to be

`[7bb8b6ec123302e43ad88384158e2347efcfef19600b821431e8e09504046595,1f57c6ad7358ac73b73730eabb54b1bea7b785df2e4502291ed99b08af625def]`, it can not work, why?

Answer (score 3):

for the example in the question body, the format should be altered to `["0x7bb8b6ec123302e43ad88384158e2347efcfef19600b821431e8e09504046595","0x1f57c6ad7358ac73b73730eabb54b1bea7b785df2e4502291ed99b08af625def"]`, it will be OK