# Concatenation of different datatypes and hashing it

Tags: addresses, hash, sha3

How can I concat two different datatypes and then hash it?
for example: `sha3(int8 + address)`

Or it is also good for me hash them separately, and then  hash together.
like this: `sha3(sha3(int8) + address)`

How to do that most efficient way?

Comment: I have hash of my int8 ```sha3(num)```
And I can produce the same thing on front-end: ```Web3.utils.sha3(Web3.utils.toHex(40))```

Now I am wondering what is the most efficient and hash secure way to hash them both (my hashed int8 and hashed or not hashed address).

I can see I can concat both bytes32 two one string using this:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/how-to-concatenate-a-bytes32-array-to-a-string
and then hash it to produce my bytes32.

Can I do this somehow more efficient?

Comment: Or I think, I can do this easier like xoring both data, and then hash them.
But I am afraid that this can be not secure enough.
something like: ```sha3(sha3(int8) ^ address)```
What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate the values, cast them into `bytes`, create an output `bytes` variable and then assign each byte

```
int8 _num;
address _addr;
bytes b0 = bytes(_num);
bytes b1 = bytes(_addr);
string s0 = new string(b0.length + b1.length);
bytes b2 = bytes(s0);
uint k = 0;
for (uint i = 0; i < b0.length(); i++) { b2[k++] = b0[i] }
for (i = 0; i < b1.length(); i++) {b2[k++] = b1[i] }
```

Then you can just hash the concatenated byte array.  If you hashed these separately and then concatenated the two hashes it would probably be much less efficient (computationally) since you'd still have to write some code for concatenating them and they are much longer than the two variables.